# Finding User Address From Their Phone Number

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am working on a automobile web portal (basically its a web application for selling/buying used cars). The application is developed in Java using Spring-MVC.

For this application we are scrapping data from almost 80-90 car forums so that we can display data from these forums on our local site. For each post in these forums to be scrapped, we need the seller address (where seller is the one who posted his car on forum). While scrapping data from these forums, in many cases we get the address, but in others we don't. But we need seller address in as many post as we can and in anyway we can. So we thought to apply another alternative for this.

The alternate solution we thought is that, when we don't get seller address we look for their phone number instead and convert it into corresponding address. But the problem is that after getting seller phone number, we are not able to find a suitable way to map it to their address. Does anyone know of any free(which i would prefer) java-api which could help us achieve this?

What we have found till now is http://www.allareacodes.com/. This site is offering their database to be downloaded at $29, and even then they are claiming to provide not the complete address. Their sample data is as shown in the following table. Also they are mapping area_code to city and not the complete phone number (but that can be managed, as we only need to map US phone numbers). The main problem with this one is that they don't offer complete address and they ask for $29. We don't want to waste our $29 if there is really a better solution for free.

```
area_code   primary_city    state   timezone
202         WASHINGTON       DC     Eastern
203         NEW HAVEN        CT     Eastern
204         SAINT CLAUDE     MB     Central
205         BIRMINGHAM       AL     Central
206         SEATTLE          WA     Pacific
```

Any help is appreciated.

Let us know if anyone need any more detail?

### Edit 1:

As pointed out in comment we cannot rely on area_code as people take out their cell phones to distant area codes.

Also by seeing the Google link given in first answer, we see that multiple cities are associated with one area_code. so this is one more problem.

Comment: You still will have a problem even if you go with www.allareacodes.com because a user's area code does not necessarily indicate where they live, as many people take out cell phones with distant area codes.

Comment: Thats a good point. we didn't think of it. but if i am to cut out this solution, i would need another.

Answer (score 1):

as the comment said, you can not depend on the area code to get the person geo location, you will find a lot  of people live in some place and their area code is different, but any way google have the area code services may be you can use it, this is the link 
https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1tg2mkYjGB3J5i03FqSkQsq8foq6lH5knfAgFO9I#rows:id=1

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but if i can't rely on area_code, then do you have any other solution you propose?